# Python: Can't replace special/foreign characters in text file

Tags: python

I have a text file named g.txt. It holds a large collection of German words. I am looking to replace äÄöÖüÜß characters. I started with ü and want to replace it with the html Unicode call &#252;  However it throws no error, but does not work. I have tried to replace normal letters and it works with the code below, but not with the German umlaut.

```
reading_file = open("g.txt", "r")

new_file_content = ""
for line in reading_file:
  stripped_line = line.strip()
  new_line = stripped_line.replace("ü", "&#252")
  new_file_content += new_line +"\n"
reading_file.close()

writing_file = open("g.txt", "w")
writing_file.write(new_file_content)
writing_file.close()
```

Any help apreciated!

Comment: You're using Python 3, right?

Comment: yeah I am 3.8..

Comment: You should build a limited file (one single line and one single `ü`) and print the code of all the characters of the line with `hex(ord())`. It would help to understand what is actually happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use encoding `utf8`. Try this code

```
reading_file = open("abc.data", "r", encoding="utf8")

new_file_content = ""
for line in reading_file.readlines():
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    new_line = stripped_line.replace("ü", "&#252")
    new_file_content += new_line +"\n"
reading_file.close()

writing_file = open("abc.data2", "w", encoding="utf8")
writing_file.write(new_file_content)
writing_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the unicode escape version of character you want to replace.

`new_line = stripped_line.replace("\u0252", "&#252")`

Comment: Just tested, doesn't seem to work i tried "\u0252" and "\\u0252" variation. Ty though